# Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("W0:0", shape=(5, 5, 1, 6), dtype=float32_ref)

Tags: graph, shapes, tensor

**I am trying to understand the basics of this error, on what parameters it depends.
I have need trying to run a neural network model and want to play with number of filters and filter sizes.**

## Reshape training and testing image

```
train_X = data.train.images.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
test_X = data.test.images.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
train_y = data.train.labels
test_y = data.test.labels

print (train_X.shape, test_X.shape)
#____________________
training_iters = 200 
learning_rate = 0.001 
batch_size = 4

# MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_input = 28

# MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)
n_classes = 10

#both placeholders are of type float
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28,28,1])

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,10])

#_____________
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x) 

def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],padding='SAME')
#___________
tf.reset_default_graph()
weights = {
    'wc1': tf.get_variable('W0', shape=(5,5,1,6), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc2': tf.get_variable('W1', shape=(3,3,6,64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc3': tf.get_variable('W2', shape=(3,3,64,128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wd1': tf.get_variable('W3', shape=(4*4*128,128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'out': tf.get_variable('W6', shape=(128,n_classes), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
}
biases = {
    'bc1': tf.get_variable('B0', shape=(6), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc2': tf.get_variable('B1', shape=(64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc3': tf.get_variable('B2', shape=(128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bd1': tf.get_variable('B3', shape=(128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'out': tf.get_variable('B4', shape=(10), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
}
#__________________
def conv_net(x, weights, biases):  

    # here we call the conv2d function we had defined above and pass the input image x, weights wc1 and bias bc1.
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling), this chooses the max value from a 2*2 matrix window and outputs a 14*14 matrix.
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    # here we call the conv2d function we had defined above and pass the input image x, weights wc2 and bias bc2.
    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling), this chooses the max value from a 2*2 matrix window and outputs a 7*7 matrix.
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling), this chooses the max value from a 2*2 matrix window and outputs a 4*4.
    conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3, k=2)


    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv3, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Output, class prediction
    # finally we multiply the fully connected layer with the weights and add a bias term. 
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out
```

**I am trying to understand the basics of this error, on what parameters it depends.
I have need trying to run a neural network model and want to play with number of filters and filter sizes.**

Comment: Please add your code as text and some details about your question.

Comment: image of code is attached as link https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoRse.png

Comment: Ehm...please read my comment once again.

Comment: sorry, kindly now check and please make me understand in details Thanks in advance